# Statistical Test for Some Inequality Condition

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inequality

Suppose that we have three random variables, named $V_1, V_2$ and $V_3$.
Here, I want to test the following inequality:

$V_1 \geq V_2, V_3$

Is there any reference dealing with this topic?

Comment: Maybe you want an intersection-union test?

Comment: Thank you for the comment :) I will refer that